# xml button link to for loop

Tags: android

I am trying to get a button in an XML doc to add new textfields and checkboxes, I have the for loop that does what I want, but I don't understand how I am suposed to link my button to access a specific part of a java file.

How do i implement?

edit.

Here is my forloop that I want my button to access when pressed (generate textfields)

And Generally I want to know if it is possible to link a xml button to a loop in java and
If not, what can I do in order to get my button to generate textfields?

```
    for(int i = 0; i <5; i++){
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
cb.setText("I'm an egg!");
EditText et1 = new EditText(this);
et1.setText("Listitemz!");
ll.addView(et1);
ll.addView(cb);
```

Comment: I guess we'll have to see some code in order to help you.

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

in XML:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button" ..... />
```

in java file:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button)
```

Now you can use `button` object from `Button` class.
Is it what you mean by linking?

Comment: Thanks! So now I have my button in java, but how do I make the button generate textfields?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly you want the button to access and run the for loop?

**Step 1:**
First create the button in xml.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Step 2:**
Create the link in your activity.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

**Step 3:**
Assign an onClickListener to your button and put the for-loop inside.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for(int i = 0; i <5; i++){
                   CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
                   cb.setText("I'm an egg!");
                   EditText et1 = new EditText(this);
                   et1.setText("Listitemz!");
                   ll.addView(et1);
                   ll.addView(cb);
                }                   
        }
    });
```

Now whenever the button is pressed your for-loop will run, if you have any questions please let me know.

**NOTE:** You may need the following imports -

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
```